# Android: обновление данных в Fragment при обновлении данных в Activity

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение такой проблемы:

Использую NavigationDraver, при нажатии на итем меню в активити обрабатывается нажатие и  грузится фрагмент, в него передаются некоторые данные. В активити есть сокет, по которому приходят данные с сервера, как мне передать новые данные во фрагмент так, что бы не создавать новый фрагмент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Над данными сообразите `ContentProvider` и грузите данные в фрагменте из этого провайдера через `Cursor`. Тогда как только будет обновление данных, то данные во фрагменте обновятся автоматом (благодаря связке `ContentProvider -> Cursor -> Fragment`) - это вообще рекомендованный паттерн в Android'е для обновления сетевых данных на юай.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ - Спасибо! Реализовал этот паттерн, хотя и потратил много времени что бы понять, как это приблизительно работает)

Comment: @ua6xh я тоже в первый раз помучился, зато потом уже все просто и понятно!

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ - Да, паттерн довольно простой в общем, но вот его реализация заставляет помучиться. Подскажите пожалуйста, не будет ли накладно, если 1 активити будет работать одновременно с тремя контент провидерами? Данные, которые у меня приходят по сокету, обновляют меню и два листвью в фрагментах. Это нормальная практика, наличие большого количество провидеров, которые всё обновляют сами? Я замечал, что в приложение Вконтакте - меню и  основной контент не синхронизированы. Обновляя сообщения, цифра с количеством сообщений не сразу обновляется в меню. Может это неспроста?

Comment: @ua6xh Если я правильно понимаю, то дорогим (в смысле времени) может стать поиск собственно самого провайдера в системе и в этом случае (когда много провайдеров) рекомендуется использовать `ContentProviderClient`, который как бы *фиксирует* в пределах активити провайдера. Покопай в этом направлении. Другим способом уменьшения количества провайдеров является игра через `UriMatcher` - то есть в зависимости от `path` на разные таблицы/запросы в пределах одного провайдера.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ - Спасибо за информацию! =)

Answer (score 2):

`FragmentManager.findFragmentById()` и `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` помогут вам получить существующий экземпляр фрагмента.

Как вариант, можно так же послать `Intent` с обновлёнными данными, которые фрагмент поймает в установленном им `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Можете рассказать немного, как правильно организовать вариант с `BroadcastReceiver`?
У меня вот такая структура:

`CirclesActivity extends FragmentActivity`, в нем создается меню и обрабатывается выбор. При выборе любого пункта меню, создается `CircleFragment` и выполняется `replace`.

Comment: `CircleFragment` в свою очередь содержит в себе `ViewPager` и `PagerTabStrip`.
В адаптере для `ViewPager` находятся два фрагмента: 

 1. `NotificationsListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`
 2. `OverviewListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`

Вот мне надо обновить данные в `NotificationsListFragment`.

![alt text][1] ![alt text][2]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/SW9oNr8.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/K23VwKh.png

Answer (score 0):

При создании фрагмента хранить ссылку на этот фрагмент в Activity.